# Can I get the status text from an NSHTTPURLResponse?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, http, nsurlconnection

If I use NSURLConnection to get data from a server and it sends back a response that begins with, say:

HTTP/1.1 406 Some string of text here

Is there any way I can retrieve the status text "Some string of text here"?  I know how to get the status code, and I know about localizedStringForStatusCode:, but in this case I need access to the specific text sent back.

Comment: Does `-allHeaderFields` not contain that information?

Comment: Not that I can see.  Strictly speaking, this is the status line, not a header line in the form "key: value".

Comment: Ok good to know, dont forgot to go through your previous questions and accept answered on any of them that helped answer question including this one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), which provides this as `-requestStatusMessage`. Or you can use Core Foundation's `CFHTTP`, which provides `CFHTTPMessageCopyResponseStatusLine`. I don't believe there's a good way to get to the `CFHTTPMessage` from `NSHTTPURLResponse` unfortunately. Of course, `ASIHTTPRequest` is pretty awesome anyway.